# What is the nUnit equivalent for a mstest XML file DataSource?

Tags: nunit, mstest

I'm moving some tests from mstest to nUnit.
MsTest allows to specify a XML file as the input data for the test:

```
[TestMethod()]
[DeploymentItem("ProjectName\\TestData\\file.xml")]
[DataSource("Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.DataSource.XML",
       "|DataDirectory|\\TestData\\file.xml",
       "Row", 
       DataAccessMethod.Sequential)]
public void Test() {}
```

How can I have a similar test setup in nUnit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NUnit doesn't have direct support to read a custom xml file. However it does provide support to specify a method (refer for examples to the docs for [the TestCaseSource attribute](http://nunit.org/index.php?p=testCaseSource&r=2.6)) which will compute test case inputs for a parameterized test.

You can implement this method to read the inputs from an XML / CSV or whatever custom logic you choose.